# Netbeans 7.1.2 - project source folders in a tree (hierarchical) view, rather then a flat view?

Tags: netbeans, package, treeview, netbeans-7, netbeans-7.1

How can I get a tree view for Netbeans 7.1.2? The FAQ http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqTreePackageView appears to be for older versions of Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to turn the package list

```
java.io
java.lang
java.net
java.util
java.util.concurrent
```

into a package tree

```
java
  io
  lang
  net
  util
    concurrent
```

This is a new option in NetBeans 7.2 which is in beta now. I installed it today and haven't had any issues yet. BTW, did you try the suggestion in the FAQ? It could be that only the FAQ is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

**RMB on blank space in projects window > View Java packages As > Tree / Reduced tree**

Personaly I recommend reduced tree.